# Adding a class to the clicked item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am beginner in webdevelopment
I have this module: http://serwer1356363.home.pl/_nauka/

After clicking on the items in the popup, I would like to:

1. A "frame" (selected-material class) has been added to the clicked element - in the popup
2. The selected option in select is highlighted (it works)
3. Popup has closed (it works).

I have 2 selections and I would like that selecting (marking with frames)

My JS code looks like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.select-material-body', function(e) {
        if($('.material-type-input').val() == 1){
            $(".select-material").removeClass("selected-material");
            $(this).addClass("selected-material");
            $('select[name=product-material-body]').val($(this).attr('id'));
            $('.product-material-body').selectpicker('refresh');
            $('#material-dialog-modal').modal('hide');
        } else{
            $(".select-material").removeClass("selected-material");
            $(this).addClass("selected-material");
            $('select[name=product-material-front]').val($(this).attr('id'));
            $('.product-material-front').selectpicker('refresh');
            $('#material-dialog-modal').modal('hide');
        }
    });
```

Html:

```
<div id="material-dialog-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body pt-0">
                    <h3 class="select-material-title px-3"></h3>
                    <form method="get" action="getMaterials" class="px-3 select-material-url">
                        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="" class="material-type-input">
                        <div class="inner-addon rounded-0 modal-search-form">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control product-query-string-body"
                                placeholder="Szukaj produktu" aria-label="Wpisz nazwę lub kod koloru" name="query"
                                value="" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div class="row material-list px-5 pt-4 dynamic-materials">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Anyone know how to do it?

Please help

Comment: what do you mean with *frame*? and why the code is the same for both `if/else`?

Comment: look here: http://serwer1356363.home.pl/_nauka/ - I have 2 select.I would like to mark selected items in modal for each select separately